# How to optimize this SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have one-to-many tables `Payment` and `PaymentFlows` to keep track of payment workflows.

For different managers, they are interested in certain workflows only. So whenever a payment reach a certain workflow, a list is provided to them.

For example,

```
 Payment 1 - A) Apply
             B) Checked
             C) Approved by Manager
             D) Approved by CFO
             E) Cheque issued

 Payment 2 - A) Apply
             B) Checked
             C) Approved by Manager

 Payment 3 - A) Apply
             B) Checked
             C) Approved by Manager

 Payment 4 - A) Apply
             B) Checked
```

To show all payments at workflow `C`, what I did is:

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.search_by_workflow(flow_code)
    self.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM payments P INNER JOIN (
        SELECT payment_id FROM (
          SELECT * FROM (
            SELECT * FROM payment_flows F
            ORDER BY F.payment_flow_id DESC
          ) latest GROUP BY payment_id
        ) flows WHERE flows.code = flow_code)
      ) IDs ON IDs.payment_id = P.payment_id ORDER BY P.payment_id DESC LIMIT 100;")
  end

end
```

so:

```
@payments = Payment.search_by_workflow('Approved by Manager')
```

returns: `Payment 2` and `3`

However, the performance is not very good (5 to 7 seconds for 15,000 payments and 55,000 workflows).

How can I improve the performance?

UPDATE (with table structures):

```
CREATE TABLE `payments` (
  `payment_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `payment_type_code` varchar(50) default 'PETTY_CASH',
  `status` varchar(16) NOT NULL default '?',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`payment_id`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `payment_type_code` (`payment_type_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `payment_flows` (
  `payment_flow_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `payment_id` int(11) default NULL,
  `code` varchar(64) default NULL,
  `status` varchar(255) NOT NULL default 'new',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`payment_flow_id`),
  KEY `payment_id` (`payment_id`),
  KEY `code` (`code`),
  KEY `status` (`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

UPDATE (with `name_scope`):

```
named_scope :by_workflows, lambda { |workflows| { :conditions =>  [ "EXISTS (
          SELECT 'FLOW'
          FROM payment_flows pf
          WHERE pf.payment_id = payments.payment_id
          AND pf.proc_code IN (:flows)
          AND NOT EXISTS (
              SELECT 'OTHER'
              FROM payment_flows pfother
              WHERE pfother.payment_id = pf.payment_id
              AND pfother.payment_flow_id > pf.payment_flow_id
          )
      )", { :flows => workflows } ]}
    }
```

for convenience, e.g.:

```
Payment.by_workflows(['Approved by Manager', 'Approved by CFO']).count
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Why payment1 not consider? Has Approved by Manager state too (as 2 and 3)

Comment: @JoeTaras only the latest state which matches is need

Comment: @ohho: Ok, I didn't understand better before your clarification

Comment: @ohho: Please can post the structure of payments and payment_flows tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM payment p
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 'FLOW'
    FROM payment_flows pf
    WHERE pf.payment_id = p.payment_id
    AND pf.code = flow_code 
    AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 'OTHER'
        FROM payment_flows pf2
        WHERE pf2.payment_id = pf.payment_id
        AND pf2.payment_flow_id > pf.payment_flow_id
    )
)
```

**Pay attention:** in the query flow_code is a variable with the code you want to search

I've added a main EXISTS condition about the presence of flow_code and a nested NOT EXISTS condition about the absence of other id of the same payment next about flow_code.

Tell me if is it OK about better performance.

Comment: Wow! This improves the performance from ~4s to ~200ms. Thanks!

Comment: Good! Have a nice day ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are defining "latest" payment_flows for a given payment to be the row with largest value of payment_flow_id.

For better performance, if you can replace a couple of your indexes on payment_flow_id

by ADDING these indexes

```
  ... ON payment_flow_id(code,payment_id,payment_flow_id)
  ... ON payment_flow_id(payment_id,payment_flow_id)
```

and DROPPING these (now redundant) indexes

```
  ... ON payment_flow_id(code) 
  ... ON payment_flow_id(payment_id)
```

I would suggest this query:

```
  SELECT p.*
    FROM payments p
    JOIN ( SELECT c.payment_id
                , MAX(c.payment_flow_id) AS flow_id
             FROM payment_flows c
            WHERE c.code =   :flow_code       /* <-- query parameter */
            GROUP BY c.payment_id
            ORDER BY c.code DESC, c.payment_id DESC 
         ) d
      ON d.payment_id = p.payment_id
    LEFT
    JOIN payment_flows n
      ON n.payment_id      = d.payment_id
     AND n.payment_flow_id > d.payment_flow_id
   WHERE n.payment_id IS NULL
   ORDER BY d.payment_id DESC
   LIMIT 100
```

The inline view query "d" gets the payment_flow_id (if any) for the specified code (**:flow_code**), so it returns only the payments that are at least that far in the processing flow.

The query uses an anti-join pattern to exclude rows that have a payment_flow_id that is "later" than the one for the specified code.

The anti-join is an outer join, to return all rows from the left side, along with matching rows from the right side, with a condition in the WHERE clause that excludes all rows that had a matching row. (Note the inequality comparison, only rows that had a "later" payment_flow_id values would be a match.)

There's no guarantee that this will be faster.

But with the suggested index improvements, it should get you nice looking EXPLAIN output.  (Using EXPLAIN is a pretty good handle on the access plan that will be used by the query.)